# mysql_fetch_array and mysql_query return nothing on a call from two different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables books and users. books has a column `id` and users has a column called `book_id`. users table is populated by info about users who bought books from the store including the column `book_id` which referees to the `id` from books table.

My questions is, I have been trying to do this but with no success.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books, users WHERE books.id='$id' OR users.id='$id' ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $info .= $row[0] . " " . $row[1] . "<br/>";
}
echo $info;
```

Table books has some data but users is empty and I am getting nothing as an output!!! What am I missing??

Additional attempts:

`SELECT * FROM books, users WHERE books.id='$id'` returns empty results

`SELECT * FROM books WHERE books.id='$id'` returns 5 rows

Comment: Have you echoed out your query to make sure it is correct? Did you run it from the mysql command line to see if it works there? Do you get any error messages? Whjat have you done to debug this?

Comment: I add `or die(mysql_error());` at the end of the `query` statement and it didnt complain

Comment: What about the other troubleshooting steps i mentioned?

Comment: yup tried it as a mysql command and get `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0006 sec )`

Comment: Then your expectations do not reflect the reality that is your database. Start removing parts of your `where` clause and see what happens.

Comment: That's my issue. This statement does return 5 rows `SELECT * FROM books WHERE books.id='$id'` but why when I add the OR statement it returns 0.

Comment: [Please, don't use mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in new code. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [_prepared statements_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which.

Comment: Do you need to get all records from two table?

Comment: yes, both tables are small. one has 3 columns and the other 4

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the correct `JOIN`.

> Table books has some data **but users is empty** and I am getting nothing as an output

Since `users` table contains no records you need to use `LEFT | RIGHT` or `FULL` join to get the result set, depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Therefore try to change your query to

```
SELECT * 
  FROM books b LEFT JOIN
       users u ON b.id=u.book_id
 WHERE ...
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2699a/6)**

Comment: @Khalid Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?